# Simple algortihm for evaluating eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In our lecture notes, there is a line where one has to find eigenvectors for the previously calculated eigenvalues

> $\lambda_1$ $=$ $\sqrt{61} \over 2$ - $3 \over 2$,
>
> $\lambda_1$ $=$ -$\sqrt{61} \over 2$ - $3 \over 2$.

For the first eigenvalue, our professor just noted:

> "A possible eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\sqrt{61} \over 2$ - $3 \over 2$ is $($$3$ , $\sqrt{61} - 5 \over 2$)."

I know that there is an algorithm for solving a problem like this, but when I tried it, it got a little bit messy. Therefore, I wondered if there was actually a way to "see" the eigenvectors directly - or if there was at least an algorithm that needs only a few simple steps.

The matrix is:

> [image]

Comment: That's what I know so far, yes.

Comment: Yes, did it.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "see" the eigenvectors *directly*, no more than it is easy to predict the solution of any given linear system of equations. Because this is exactly what the problem is; solving

$$(A - \lambda I)x = 0.$$

Of course, in some cases, it can be done, *e.g.* if $A - \lambda I$ turns out to be a matrix with some special structure. But to a general extent, there is no global method. Now, solving a $2 \times 2$ system is usually not too hard nor long; you just have to remain rigorous.

There are a lot of methods to approximate $x$ decently though. Yet they are inadequate to be computed by hand, since they usually imply matrix power iterations and/or vectors normalization.